# Setting class path in particular jar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jar, executable-jar

I want to include other supporting jars in particular jar. I have changed my manifest file
as follows

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Created-By: Apache Maven

Built-By: kedarj

Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35

Class-Path: abc.jar xyz.jar commons-io-1.3.2.jar hibernate-c3p0-4.1.7.Final.jar javax.inject-1.jar spring-data-mongodb-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar hibernate-ehcache-4.1.7.Final.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar ehcache-web-2.0.4.jar Cache-1.0.3.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar commons-lang-2.3.jar

Main-Class: abc.SomeClass

I have abc.jar as main jar and all others are supporting jars which are kept is same folder. Please help me out to set class-path correctly.

Comment: What's not working about it? It looks fine. Did you remember to add the next-line carriage at the end?

Comment: Can you please explain?? how to add next-line carriage??

Comment: You need to have an extra line at the very end after `Main-Class: abc.SomeClass`. In the manifest, at the end of that line, just hit `ENTER` to make sure there is an extra line

Comment: Can you please explain in brief what is correct way to write manifest for such scenario?

Comment: Have a look at [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929438/create-jar-with-custom-manifest-with-multiple-libraries-in-classpath) and [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) and [**Working with Manifests**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) from the Oracle tutorial

Comment: How can I refer entire folder of jars to class path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum characters in the classpath list per line should not exceed 72.

so use separate line after 72 character.

for eg.

```
Class-Path: abc.jar xyz.jar commons-io-1.3.2.jar hibernate-c3p0-4.1.7.Final.jar
  javax.inject-1.jar spring-data-mongodb-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I have declared each jar file to new line like this

Class-Path: abc.jar
xyz.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
hibernate-c3p0-4.1.7.Final.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
spring-data-mongodb-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar

But now I am getting error 'Invalid or corrupt jar file'