# Running multiple SpringBootApplication classes from a single maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Is there a way to specify which SpringBootApplication's main class to run when running `mvn spring-boot:run`? The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#mainClass) say I can use mainClass parameter to specify which main class to run. But I am not sure how to specify it in command line. I have tried `mvn -DmainClass=mypackage.myclass spring-boot:run` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by having a placeholder in the plugin configuration of spring-boot

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainclass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and then running different classes

```
mvn -Dmainclass=mypackage.myclass spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score -1):

**Two answers to your question**

1. You have to create a MANIFEST.MF file in src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and give an attribute like this as given below
   Main-Class= com.yourfilename
2. You can use maven jar plugin to define main-class configuration in your manifest file, please use this links below which will help you.
3. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929438/create-jar-with-custom-manifest-with-multiple-libraries-in-classpath) 
   [link 2](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html)

Comment: in the manifest I can specify only one main class. But I would want to be able to specify which class to run on the fly. Something like `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`